# Entity Framework Code First post migration step?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Is there some way to add a post migration method to Code First EF migration?

All the stored proc's are in the Visual Studio project. Right now there is an approach to load the stored proc resource from the file and put it into it's own migration:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    var script = ScriptMgr.LoadStoredProc( "StoredProcThatChanged.sql" );
    migrationBuilder.Sql( script );
}
```

There is a weak link in this process:  Each time the script changes (StoredProcThatChanged.sql) a new migration needs to be created to make sure it executes again.  The problem is the previous migration is also loading the same file.  When generating a new script, the process reads in the one file both times, effectively changing the previous migration.  Which is a classic no-no.

This would be resolved if there is a post migration method where ALL stored proc's can be reapplied to the DB.  Is such a step possible?  If so, now is it done?

---

I have been digging into the [efcore source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore) and it looks like it is possible, not ideal, but there might be a way...

It looks like efcore has an interface called IMigrator.  It contains the method string GenerateScript(...).  The implementation of it, class Migrator, has comments all over the place saying that it's implementation of GenerateScript is internal and subject to change.  But...  It looks to me like I can achieve my end goal:

```
    class MyMigrator : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator
{
    public string GenerateScript(
            string? fromMigration = null,
            string? toMigration = null,
            MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options = MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions.Default) 
    {
        var result = base.GenerateScript( fromMigration, toMigration, options);
        results += MyPostSteps(...);
        return results;
    }
}
```

Will this work and does anyone know how I might go about replacing the default Migrator with the MyMigrator?

Comment: Have you looked into EF Core MigrationOperations? [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations#using-a-migrationoperation)

Comment: Yes, I have looked into those doc's and that isn't what I am looking to do.  I will add more detail to the question above about what I have found out today...